# Where to get QGIS toolbar icons?

Tags: qgis, download, toolbar, icon

Does anybody know where to download the QGIS toolbar icons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the icons in the Github repository: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/images/themes/default

Answer (score 1):

QGIS default icon set uses files from OSGeo Graphics Project.

For more info and other files visit:

http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/OSGeo_Graphics

Answer (score 1):

From the online documentation: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/_images/
... and http://robert.szczepanek.pl/icons.php.

Answer (score 0):

You can now look at this webpage that make an index with a preview to list how to reuse existing QGIS https://static.geotribu.fr/toc_nav_ignored/qgis_resources_preview_table/

[image]

For an "how to" about the way it has been done, look at https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=&sl=fr&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.geotribu.fr%2Farticles%2F2021%2F2021-02-02_pyqgis_previsualiser_images_integrees%2F (original content in French, so using a Google translate link)